# How to remove empty namespace attribute on manually added xml string when serializing object?

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, xmlserializer

I am using XmlSerializer to output my object model to XML. Everything works very well but now I need to add several lines of pre-built XML to the object without building classes for each line. After lots of searching, I found that I can convert the xml string to an XmlElement using XmlDocument's LoadXml and DocumentElement calls. I get the XML I want except that the string section has an empty namespace. How can I eliminate the empty namespace attribute? Is there a better way to add an xml string to the object and have it be serialized properly?

Note: I am only creating output so I don't need to deserialize the generated XML. I am fairly new to the C#, .NET world, and hence, XmlSerialize.

Here is my code:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public XmlElement Extension { get; set; }

    public Book()
    {
    }

    public void AddExtension()
    {
        string xmlString = "<AdditionalInfo>" +
                                "<SpecialHandling>Some Value</SpecialHandling>" +
                           "</AdditionalInfo>";

        this.Extension = GetElement(xmlString);
    }

    public static XmlElement GetElement(string xml)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.LoadXml(xml);

        return doc.DocumentElement;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestSerialization p = new TestSerialization();

    Book bookOne = new Book();

    bookOne.Title = "How to Fix Code";
    bookOne.Author = "Dee Bugger";

    bookOne.AddExtension();

    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Book), "http://www.somenamespace.com");

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\BookReport.xml"))
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, bookOne);
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Book xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.somenamespace.com">
  <Title>How to Fix Code</Title>
  <Author>Dee Bugger</Author>
  <Extension>
    <AdditionalInfo xmlns="">
      <SpecialHandling>Some Value</SpecialHandling>
    </AdditionalInfo>
  </Extension>
</Book>
```

It is the xmlns="" on AdditionalInfo that I want to eliminate.  I believe this coming out because there is no association between the XmlDocument I created and the root serialized object, so the XmlDocument creates its own namespace. How can I tell the XmlDocument (and really, the generated XmlElement) that it belongs to the same namespace as the serialized object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is added because the parent elements have a namespace and your `AdditionalInfo` element does not. The `xmlns=""` attribute changes the default namespace for that element and its children.

If you want to get rid of it, then presumably you want the `AdditionalInfo` element to have the same namespace as its parent.  In which case, you need to change your XML to this:

```
string xmlString = @"<AdditionalInfo xmlns=\"http://www.somenamespace.com\">" +
                    "<SpecialHandling>Some Value</SpecialHandling>" +
                    "</AdditionalInfo>";
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. That means I would have to add it to the SpecialHandling line as well.  I won't be building the string, just adding it to the object.  I would have to parse the string and add the namespace in every proper location.  I looked at XmlDocument, LoadXml, and DocumentElement in hopes of just setting the namespace once but there doesn't seem to be a way. Am I missing an option?  Is this approach even correct for adding a bulk of xml to be serialized?

Comment: @sldorman no, the string as above is all you'd need. The default namespace is inherited (hence it only added a single `xmlns=""` before, and there is only a single declaration in the wider document). If you have to parse the XML first, it's trivial to change the namespace of all elements using LINQ to XML.

Comment: You're right.  I had a typo when I tried it that caused the 2nd line to have an empty namespace.  Thanks again.